# openCV-C++ image sum

Tags: c++, image, opencv

** I am trying to make an image out of 2 images (50% of img1+50% of img 2) but the result is always a grey image**

```
#pragma once
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>

void help()
{
    std::cout << "Not enough parameters!" << std::endl;
    system("exit");
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    if (argc < 3)
    {

        help();
        system("pause");
        exit(-1);
    }

    cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread(argv[1]);
    cv::Mat image2 = cv::imread(argv[2]);
```

*//This is where i create the new image...structure*

```
    cv::Mat new_img(image1.rows, image1.cols, CV_8UC1);

    for (int i = 0; i < image1.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image1.cols; j++)
        {
```

*//Here i fill the new image with the sum of the other 2*

```
            new_img.at<uchar>(cv::Point(j, i)) =
                (image1.at<cv::Vec<uchar, 3>>(cv::Point(j, i)).val[0] / 2 + image2.at<cv::Vec<uchar, 3>>(cv::Point(j, i)).val[0]) / 2 +
                 (image1.at<cv::Vec<uchar, 3>>(cv::Point(j, i)).val[1] / 2 + image2.at<cv::Vec<uchar, 3>>(cv::Point(j, i)).val[1] / 2) +
                 (image1.at<cv::Vec<uchar, 3>>(cv::Point(j, i)).val[2] / 2 + image2.at<cv::Vec<uchar, 3>>(cv::Point(j, i)).val[2] / 2);
        }

    }
    cv::namedWindow("Original1", 0);
    cv::imshow("Original1", image1);
    cv::namedWindow("Original2", 0);
    cv::imshow("Original2", image2);
    cv::namedWindow("Suprapuse", 0);
    cv::imshow("Suprapuse", new_img);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    int a = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted

Comment: first you need include the correct header !

Answer (score 0):

You set new_img as CV_8UC1, the result is gray. If you want add two color image as a new image, you can use addWeight and set two weight to 0.5.

Comment: Afaik its called addWeighted but I didnt check.

Answer (score -1):

The new image is necessary to be CV_8CV3 (three channels) because your imag1 and img2 is color vec where 3 it's three channels => your image is color not grayscale (CV_8CV1). 
But I'm not sure :D